# kubuntu 22.04 'oh, no! something has gone wrong'

Tags: boot, kubuntu, xorg, gui, xserver

I implore your help. I'm an average linux user and I'm stucked in tty.
My network does not work and when i try to launch `startx` it shows me the screen 'oh, no! something has gone wrong'.
All hapened after a apt upgrade command. Now:

```
sudo dmesg
lockdown: modprobe: unsigned module loading is restricted; see man kernel_lockdowon.7
lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

is this a possible problem?

in another log i got:

```
failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03f f vesa :refusing to run on uefi xinit connection to x server lost
```

I've managed to enter my sistem with a livecd of ubuntu, and through chroot to update and upgrade my system succesfully. But the problem still remain: Can't access to my system with Grapical Interface.

`systemctl restart sddm.service`

```
debugsfs: File 'radeon_ring_gfx' in directory 0 already present!
debugsfs: File 'radeon_ring_cp1' in directory 0 already present!
debugsfs: File 'radeon_ring_cp2' in directory 0 already present!
debugsfs: File 'radeon_ring_dma1' in directory 0 already present!
debugsfs: File 'radeon_ring_dma2' in directory 0 already present!
```

and `systemctl status sddm` says me:

```
loaded
active(exited)
```

I've modified `fstab`file for my / device from `errors=remount-ro` to `errors=remount-rw`
and after launching another time `startx` it returns me:

```
waiting for x server to begin accepting connection sta(EE)
Fatal server error:
Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tx0-lock
....
xinit:giving up
xinit:unable to connect to x server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
xauth: (argv):1: bad display name "127.0.0.1localhost:0" in remove command
```

I don't understand much of this. please help. Thankyou

Now my root file system is owned by root and it gave me "read only file system"

Comment: `/tmp` should be owned by `root` but readable and writeable by all users, e.g. have permissions `drwxrwxrwt`. Note the sticky bit at the end. Do `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` if permissions are otherwise.